# SailsJS only for API Processes (?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

is there a way to use SailsJS only as an API?

I mean, once I download the Sails project I do not want to see the views or any other stuff there, all I want is use Sails as an API.

Comment: maybe this could get you started. http://www.jlmonteagudo.com/2014/06/rest-api-development-with-sails-js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sails provides APIs by default. Controllers by default returns `res.json({})`. You can create views only if you need it (`res.view()`).

For example, create a user controller with actions `index` and `edit` as follows:

```
sails generate controller user index edit
```

Now, when you access `http://localhost:1337/user/edit`, you can see the default JSON response.

Learn more about sails controllers here: [Controllers](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Controllers)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. 
I imagine you have followed the instructions that are on their page, to install it:

```
$ sudo npm install sails -g
$ sails new testProject
```

You have everything described [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts). But for sure, you will configure the endpoints of your REST API on the routes definition, and if you don't want to expose any views, it's perfectly fine.